# Adding Google Maps Activity to button using Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to add new Google Maps Activity to a button in my main activity here is the code. 
Code for activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout_1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SITbus"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffff1b37"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff3a57ff"
        android:textSize="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:theme="@android:style/Animation"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send1"
        android:onClick="sendMessageR"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ffff2605"
        android:visibility="visible" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.harish.mysampleapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.harish.mysampleapplication.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendMessageR(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsRedActivity.class);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MapsRedActivity.java

```
package com.example.harish.mysampleapplication;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MapsRedActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_red);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
  private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

I am able to open my main activity but not able to open the Google Map Activity when I click the button. The program is not showing any errors.
Can anyone tell me where I have done wrong? and can anyone suggest me solution for this problem

Comment: Can you try to find the logs in the debugger and edit your answer to include the (relevant) logs as well? We're most likely looking for Error or Fatal level errors.

Comment: @methode there are no errors, simply map activity was never started at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create intent you have to start new activity with that intent or nothing will happen

```
public void sendMessageR(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsRedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)